# Flutter searchDelegate - Navigate and show results in another page

Tags: flutter, dart

This is something that I have done so far.

After clicking on enter key in keyboard flutter is calling 'showResults(context)'  (I think so). But what if I want to go to another screen by "Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/rro', arguments: query);"

How to stop flutting from calling 'showResults(context)' after pressing enter and in place of that navigate to another screen?

```dart
class DataSearch extends SearchDelegate<String> {
  final data = ['a', 'ab', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i'];
  final recent = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = '';
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, null);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    // Return type should be a Widget
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSuggestions(BuildContext context) {
    final suggestionList = query.isEmpty
        ? recent
        : data.where((element) => element.startsWith(query)).toList();
    return ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(

        onTap: () {
          // On tap on any ListTile I can easily go to another screen
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/rro', arguments: query);
        },
  
        title: Text(suggestionList[index]),
      ),
      itemCount: suggestionList.length,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Override the showResults(), and return a container in buildResults.
If you try to return null here, this might show some error, better return an empty container.

```dart
  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) => Container();

  @override
  void showResults(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.of(context).popAndPushNamed(
      '/rro',
      arguments: query,
    );
    super.showResults(context);
  }
```